# INFO command in linux ubuntu is installed and is giving the following error in the terminal: aborted (core image saved)

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

[image: IMAGE ERRO]

I try to use the command, but it always shows this error. I have already reinstalled and installed it and it persists.

> Info gnome-shell[2571]:   [2565:2594:1222/143805.051407:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(428)]
> Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106

Comment: After you have submitted the error for developers, you can ignore it for the future so you don't have to see it anymore.